# Microsoft SQL Server Error 1475

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

Could anybody help me please.

I am trying to mirror our SQL Server 2005 to our DR site. I have successfully done half of the databases without any issues.

However, the remaining ones all have the below Microsoft SQL Server Error 1475:

> Database mirroring cannot be enabled because the "DBNAME" database may have bulk logged changes that have not been backed up. The last log backup on the principal must be restored on the mirror. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I am not sure why this is happening as I am doing nothing different to the ones that work and that is as below. The only difference is these databases are slightly larger in size than the ones now mirroring.

- Change recovery Mode to Full,
- Take a full backup on Principal,
- Take a log backup on Principal,
- Copy to DR and restore both with Norecovery,
- Start Mirroring on the Principal.

I have researched the error but most of the comments state to do the above but this is not working for me.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: i believe,this error won't occur `Database mirroring cannot be enabled because the "DBNAME" database may have bulk logged changes that have not been backed up.` if your database is under full recovery model,as all operations are fully logged